# Why can I only pass jd-formated arguments to Time of astropy?

Tags: python, astropy

As far as I understand, Time(value, format) creates a time object. This works:

```
ss = SolarSystem(Object("Sun", 28, 'red', [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]))
ss.time =  Time(2451544.5,format="jd")
```

But this doesnt:

```
ss = SolarSystem(Object("Sun", 28, 'red', [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]))
ss.time =  Time(946684800.0,format="unix")
```

It says

> ```
> Horizons Error: Cannot interpret date. Type "?!" or try YYYY-Mon-Dy {HH:MM} format.
> ```

Also, this doesnt work either:

```
ss = SolarSystem(Object("Sun", 28, 'red', [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]))
ss.time =  Time('2000-01-01 00:00:00.000',format="iso")
```

because

> BATVAR: cannot read TLIST value: 2000-01-01

What am I doing wrong? How could I for example put the todays date into the correct format as argument?

Comment: How did you import `Time`.  All of those examples work for me, and those errors don't look like they're coming from astropy.  Are you sure you're using `astropy.time.Time`?

Comment: from astropy.time import Time

Comment: What is `SolarSystem`? Can you reproduce this with just `Time` by itself? Do you have any other imports? What does `print(Time)` return?